# apr_crypto_shutdown error restarting apache, attempting to update OpenSSL for website

Tags: raspberry-pi, openssl, apache2.4, apr

Issue:
I am working on my Raspberry Pi for a home lab project. When I run curl on my website, it shows the old OpenSSL version still: Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Unix) OpenSSL/3.0.11. Yet, I see I have 3.2.1:
/tmp/openssl-3.2.1 $ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024)

I have been troubleshooting for hours with ChatGPT4 and keep getting "apr_crypto_shutdown", when attempting to restart Apache. I got into this rabbit hole because I wanted to upgrade my OpenSSL version to the latest. Perplexity AI says these are all compatible.

Details:

```
2.4.58 for Apache. 
3.2.1 for OpenSSL. (Prev ver 3.0.11) 
1.74 for APR. 
1.6.3 for APR-util.
```

I have gone through the process of redownloading APR and APR-util, extracting, recompiling, etc. I'm now thinking of redownloading OpenSSL 3.2.1. I don't know what else to do.

Goal: Restart Apache w/o the `apr_crypto_shutdown` error and that it reflects the latest OpenSSL version 3.2.1. I installed when I run curl on my website.